# Aspects that Interact With Other Aspects in Fate Core

Tags: fate-core, aspects

Let's say I have a character with the aspect "The moon brings out my primal fury," and the environment has an aspect called "Full Moon."
Would you allow that character to invoke both aspects to do virtually the same thing (such as modify the same brutal claw attack)?

It seems odd, because the Full Moon aspect might do nothing on its own, but it seems like it can interact with the other aspect to do something it doesn't normally do.

For an alternate example with possibly more meaning, let's say you're in a dungeon that has the "dim torch-light" aspect, but your character also has the "I can manipulate the flame" aspect. Which aspects can be invoked, and how, if your character says "I want to telekinetically throw torch flame at an enemy?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, if your group thinks it makes sense.

Mechanically, you're spending the resources for the benefit, so it's not "unbalanced" (as much as Fate does balance) in that regard.

More importantly/less flippantly: aspects are tags on important established facts, and their function is largely to remind the party of the fact and that we've agreed it's important to the story. What's most important, then, is what the party agrees the aspect means.

*The moon brings out my primal fury* could mean that I have primal fury ONLY when the moon is full—or it could mean that while I always have primal fury to draw on, the moon enhances my fury or makes it harder to resist. In the first case, the *Full moon* aspect invoke is a little iffy, but they're giving up the possibility of invoking that in *every other circumstance,* so there's a trade off—unless they're ensuring the game continuously takes place under the full moon, which is probably poor for the narrative. In the second case it's very justifiable: I invoke my own aspect because I have primal fury, and I invoke the moon's ability to empower my fury.

At the end of the day, this is a decision only your group can make because only your group understands the narrative these aspects are attached to.

Answer (score 3):

### Only if they each do different things.

"The moon brings out my primal fury" is an interesting and fine aspect. I'm not sold on "The moon is full" as an Environmental Aspect, but if you're going to have that, then to invoke it, it should have a separate influence on the fight: *Because the moon is full, I can see my adversary's shadow before he knows I'm there, giving me a precious few seconds to strike.* That would be worth the extra invoke, if you have the Fate Points to spare.